# wallaby.js got error >> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, visual-studio-code, wallaby.js

i tried to set up wallaby.js on visual studio code.

my project use language: node.js (es6)

1. test: mocha
2. ide: visual studio code
3. node version: v5.9.0

i always got this error when i run wallaby

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

====== my wallaby config file (wallaby.js) =======

```
module.exports = function (wallaby) {
  return {
    files: [
      'server/**/*.js',
      '!node_modules/**/*.js'
    ],
    tests: [
      'test/**/*.js'
    ],
    compilers: {
      '**/*.js': wallaby.compilers.babel()
    },
    env: {
      type: 'node',
      params: {
        runner: '--harmony --harmony_arrow_functions'
      }
    },
    testFramework: 'mocha'
  };
};
```

====== error =======

```
​SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
/PATH/config/index.js:3:0
```

====== config.index.js ======

```
'use strict'

module.exports  = {
  // do something
}
```

it looks like there is an error on line `module.exports  = {` because of the es6 syntax.

but i used node 5.9 which support es6

how should i solved this issue?

Comment: i am working with bad internet connection. thanks @mscdex for correcting content.

Comment: Your config looks ok to me. Please create a sample Github repo reproducing the issue and share it as https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues, happy to have a look and help.

Comment: Thanks @Artem Govorov, for the updated information. I will do.

Comment: Can you paste your entire config/index.js file. Sometimes with ES6 the errors are due to something else not described by the error message. For example I sometimes forget to put the arrow in my `(arrow, functions) => { ... }` which usually triggers an error like "unexpected `u`"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

i have tried to create a small project with simple test cases and wallaby.js work fine.

I am not sure what the cause is but it should be my big code not wallaby.js.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like you need to add missing semicolon at the end of first config line:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports  = {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: I write code using es6 style that allow developer to either use or not use ';'